# Sorting by column value using jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want sorting on columns which has data in key-value pair. Currently I have implemented sorting using custom sort function which based on the key i.e Id. Here I want sorting based upon the values not by the Id. How can i achieve this? can anyone help me to resolve that issue?

please find below code for your reference.

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
    url: '/LocaleRate/LocaleRates',    
    mtype: 'GET',
    datatype: "json",
    colModel: [
        { name: 'ID', hidden: true },
        {
            name: 'SourceLocaleId', index: 'SourceLocaleId', edittype: "select", formatter: 'select',
            editoptions: { value: newLocalelist },
            sorttype: function (value, rowObject) {
              return  rowObject.SourceLocaleId;
            },

        },
        {
            name: 'LocaleId', index: 'LocaleId', edittype: "select", formatter: 'select', editoptions: { value: newLocalelist },
            sorttype: function (value, rowObject) {
                return rowObject.LocaleId;
            },
        }]    )}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sent cellvalue i.e Id in Sorttype Custom function which will returns respective Values & then JQGrid will perform sorting.

Please find below steps for your reference:

```
 jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({

    url: '/LocaleRate/LocaleRates',   
    mtype: 'GET',
    datatype: "json",
    colModel: [
        { name: 'ID', hidden: true },
        {
            name: 'SourceLocaleId', label: 'Source Locale', index: 'SourceLocaleId',  edittype: "select", formatter: 'select', editoptions: { value: LoadData(LocaleURL) },
            editrules: { required: true },
            sorttype: function (value) {
                return sortData(value, 'SourceLocaleId');
            },
        },
        {
            name: 'LocaleId', label: 'Locale', index: 'LocaleId', width: 130, align: "left", editable: true, edittype: "select", formatter: 'select', editoptions: { value: LoadData(LocaleURL) }, editrules: { required: true },
            sorttype: function (value) {
                return sortData(value, 'LocaleId');
            },
        }]
   })
```

Please find SortData function as follows:

```
function sortData(key, columnName) {

    var textvalue, getData = LocaleData ;

    for (var i = 0; i < getData.length; i++) {
        if (getData[i].Value == key) {
            textvalue = getData[i].Text;
        }
    }
    return textvalue;
}
```

**Note :** LocaleData contains key-value pair data. Here I matched key with the value returns it.